# How to connect an internal Android ADB to itself

Tags: android, shell, adb

Starting from Android 4.0, there is an "adb" command in the "system/bin" folder

Using this, I want to run an ADB server/client inside the Android OS and connect to itself.

I am trying to accomplish this by a "terminal emulator" installed on my non-rooted phone [Galaxy S III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III).

I executed these commands:

```
adb devices

setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555

stop adbd

start adbd

adb kill-server

adb devices
```

At this point, it is supposed to show device itself, "emulator-5554". But it is not showing anything.

I followed the blog post *[Androidのadbのメモ(7) Androidデバイス側でadbを動かす](http://blog.kmckk.com/archives/4092970.html)*.

Comment: In short, root privilege is required.  
[See this Q&A][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The mistake in that blog is quite big.

The reason `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555` is executed is to allow the ADB daemon to be run in TCP mode at port 5555 (it is meant to run ADB wirelessly), so that other devices in the same local network can connect to your device at port 5555.

Before running `adb devices`, you've to connect your device to the ADB server running at port 5555, and to do that enter:

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

Now type `adb devices` and you would see your device.

---

You don't need root to run ADB wirelessly on the device.

Comment: "could not set property". my phone is Verizon (probably the cause) HTC One M7, android 5.0.2, lollipop

Comment: nevermind. The initial command needs to be from a computer. and i just use `adb tcpip [PORT]`

Comment: Is 5555 is only for local wireless connection? I fi want to connect my android device over the internet i need another port?

Comment: @MosheChernysh I am only aware of the possibility of using adb for local connections. For adb over internet, I think a proper question on it would be a good thing. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63871137/adb-connect-through-internet

Answer (score 1):

If unrooted, I grab adb/fastboot from the *magisk* module, using Git within [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux):

```
git clone https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/adb-ndk.git

7z x adb-ndk.zip

mkdir ~/.bin

mv adb-ndk/bin/* ~/.bin

chmod +x ~/.bin/*

export PATH=~/.bin:$PATH

mkdir tmp

sed -i 's#/data/local/tmp#~/tmp#g' ~/.bin/adb
```

From a laptop/rooted Android device via USB, enable `adb tcpip`:

```
adb tcpip 8888 (disconnect USB return to Termux)

adb connect wifi-IP:8888 or localhost:8888

adb shell
```

Now im user "shell" and allowed to execute *pm*, *settings*, *setprop*, etc.

If you get "more than one device" error, enable `adb usb` and then `adb tcpip 8888` from another device again and do `adb kill-server` in Termux before trying to connect again. If I’m quick with it, I avoid the emulator or multiple hosts connecting. ADB has an option to specify the host as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did try the same on my rooted Odroid-C1 and it works (so thanks for the link!).

But on my [Galaxy S4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4) non-rooted it did not work.
So I guess the answer here is: **you need a rooted device**.

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: **my device is not rooted**

I have installed ADB in [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux) by using *[Termux-ADB](https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-ADB)*.

In a terminal emulator, I executed these commands:

```
cd /system/bin
start adbd
```

Now in Termux, ADB automatically connected to emulator-5554 (device itself):

```
adb devices
```

Output:

```
emulator-5554        device
```

I don't know how it worked, but it worked like a charm.

Comment: It was just emulator not actual device. If your command would have worked then adb devices would have outputted device and not emulator. Access to system/bin folder without root access is next to impossible

Answer (score -3):

Anyway, I successfully authorized my device, by [CHMOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)-ing the */data/local/tmp/* directory into [777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) rwxrwxrwx.