# Adb connect through internet

Tags: android, adb, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-server

I have rooted android device. I can connect to him fine with my wifi with:

```
adb connect 192.168.XXX.XXX
```

My question is how can i connect to this rooted device through internet from other remote computer?
I mean that i will leave this device connected to my wifi. And will connect to him from another computer that not connected to my wifi.

Comment: My suggestion is that you  setup an SSH server with root access (can do everything adb shell can) and use a dynamic DNS service so that you can ssh to your device from everywhere, whatever the IP address of the device be.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203996/how-to-connect-to-android-through-ssh-over-3g-4g-public-ip

Comment: Thanks for the link i will investigate